# How to prove $F_Y(x) \leq F_X(x)$ if $P(X \leq Y) =1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $X$ is smaller than or equal to $Y$ for every trial, i.e. $P(X \leq Y) = 1$

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ the set of $\omega$ such that:

$A_1= \{\omega: X(\omega) \le x\}, A_2 = \{\omega: Y(\omega) \le x\}$.

$P(X \le x)$ can be written as $P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \le x\}) = F_X(x)$ ,

$P(Y \le x)$ can be written as $P(\{\omega: Y(\omega) \le x\}) = F_Y(x)$.

Because $X(\omega) \le Y(\omega)$ for every trial by definition, 
$X(\omega) \le Y(\omega)\le x\ $.
$A_2$ is contained in $A_1$.

So $P(Y \le x) = P(A_2) \leq P(X\leq x) = P(A_1)$ by monotonicity.

Is there anywhere I did not clarify more, or is the proof wrong from the starting point? I am glad if anyone provides me a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convince yourself that for any event $A$ with $P(A)=1$ one has $P(B)=P(B\cap A)$ for any other event $B$.

Now, for any $x$,
$$
P(Y\leqslant x)=P(Y\leqslant x,X\leqslant Y)\leqslant P(X\leqslant x,X\leqslant Y)=P(X\leqslant x)
$$
since $\{Y\leqslant x,X\leqslant Y\}\subseteq\{X\leqslant x,X\leqslant Y\}$.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean I need to prove $P(A_1^c U A_2^c) = 0$ I am completely not sure how to prove $F_X(x) - \{\omega: X>Y\} = F_X(x)$, i.e. $\{\omega: X>Y\}$  is null.

Comment: Sorry, what?$\,$

Comment: I mean, If $B = \{\omega: X>Y\}$, $P(B) = 0$. I would like to ask how can I show that for any situation s.t. there may exist $\omega$ in $B$, and subtracting $B$ from the entire sample space $\Omega$ does not change the result.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. In my post, you would take $A=\{X\leqslant Y\}$.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. So you meant to set $\Omega$ as just $\{X \le Y\}$.

Comment: + I apologize for confusion. I got very embarrassed while proving measure-theoretic questions for the first time in my life.

Comment: No, $\Omega$ is not $\{X\leqslant Y\}$.

Comment: I see.... I got stuck when I need to consider all $\omega$s in $\Omega$ which include the set $B = \{\omega: X > Y\}$. Did I say clear for now....?

Comment: "$X\leq Y$ for every trial" is the same statement as "$X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$". So here $\{X\leq Y\}=\Omega$. I prefer the direct proof of the OP.

Comment: I took his 'i.e. $P(X\leqslant Y)=1$' as the basis of his question.

Comment: @StefanHansen Do you recommend anything to add, fix or clarify there?

Comment: @drhab I am sorry. I was confused in that the statement $X \le Y$ for every trial shall not be equivalent to $P(X \leq Y) =1$, since the measure of unit set can also be zero. What should I change or add for generality?

Comment: @FrancisK. This answer is sufficient for the case $P(X\leq Y)=1$ hence also works under the stronger condition $\{X\leq Y\}=\Omega$. From your acceptance I conclude that you understand it, so you are settled. The expression $P(X\leq Y)=1$ can be reworded as: $X\leq Y$ almost surely.

Comment: @drhab I got it. Measure theory makes students think too much.