# Prove that a distribution function is stochastically smaller than another distribution function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to prove two statements:

1.) Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ such that $P(X \leq Y)=1$. Show that $F_Y(x) \leq F_X(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$. (Show that $F_X$ is stochastically smaller than $F_Y$.) Here $F_X=P(X \leq x)$ is the distribution function of X.

2.) Suppose $F$ is stochastically smaller than $G$. Show that there exist random variables $X,Y$ on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$such that $F_X = F, F_Y =G$, and $P(X \leq Y)=1$.

**Try at 1.):**
For any $x \in \mathbb R$, let $A_1$ and $A_2$ sets of $\Omega$ such that:
$$A_1= \{\omega: X(\omega) \le x\}, A_2 = \{\omega: Y(\omega) \le x\}.$$
Now, $$P(X \le x)=P(\{\omega: X(\omega) \le x\}) = F_X(x)$$ and 
$$P(Y \le x)=P(\{\omega: Y(\omega) \le x\}) = F_Y(x)$$ by defintion. Then since $P(X\leq Y)=1$, we can write $X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$, thus $X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)\leq x$. It follows that $A_2\subset A_1$, and $$F_Y(x)=P(Y\leq x)=P(A_2)\leq P(A_1)=P(X\leq x)=F_X(x)$$ by monotonicity of probability measures, thus $F_X$ is stochastically smaller than $F_Y$. As I was asking I actually found my proof to be very similar to the OP's proof [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938174/how-to-prove-f-yx-leq-f-xx-if-px-leq-y-1)
I just wanted to check if the proofs were ok.

**Try at 2.):**
Since $F,G$ are distribution functions, there exists a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$, and random variables $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R, Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that $F=F_X,G=F_Y$. But I'm not really sure where to go from this point on.

Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) is OK. For 2) there is a standard construction. Consider the probability space $(0,1)$ with Borel sets and Lebesgue measure. Let $X(\omega)=\inf \{t: F(t) \geq \omega \}$ and $Y(\omega)=\inf \{t: G(t) \geq \omega \}$. It is trivial to check that $X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega$. To show that the distribution of $X$ is $F$ show that the statements $X(\omega) \leq t$ and $F(t) \geq \omega$ are equivalent. [You will need right continuity of $F$ for this]. Taking probability of $\{\omega: X(\omega) \leq t\}$ you will see that $X$ indeed has distribution $F$. Similarly, $Y$ has distribution $F$.

Comment: "To show that the distribution of $X$ is $F$ show that the statements $X(\omega) \leq t$ and $F(t) \geq \omega$ are equivalent." Why is this so?

Comment: Also would it make more sense to use $X(\omega)$=$sup${$t:F(t)<\omega$}?

Comment: I guess this would give you a left continuous function instead of a right continuous one.

Comment: Would it matter which one I use?

Comment: It depends how distribution functions are defined. Most books define them to be right continuous.

Comment: Is $X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ since it's taking an infimum over a larger set?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Couldn't I use supremum and still use right continuity to show that $X(\omega) \leq t$ and $F(t) \leq \omega)$ are equivalent, with $X(\omega)=sup${$t:F(t)<\omega$}, and $Y$ correspondingly?